# Making a custom module that alters a view query?

Tags: 8, views

I am super new at Drupal module development, so I wanted a little bit of input on where best to go from here.

I need to create a View that shows events in a specific order that the default Views don't provide. I'm trying to make a custom module, and use `views_query_alter()` in the .module file to alter how events on my site are displayed.

I've watched so many module development tutorials and I'm still confused on where to go from here. In all the module development videos I've watched, there's an src folder with PHP code. Right now I have src->Plugin->views->query->[queryname].php, along with my other necessary folders and files.

Would I be putting my `views_query_alter()` function in there? Or in the .module file?

Sorry for the sheer stupidity of this question, just trying to figure out where best to go from here. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just write your own query instead of use Views vs fight with Views? Otherwise I'd add a numeric field for sorting on nodes and order the view.

Comment: @Kevin when you say write my own query, where else do I do that other than in a custom view/module?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Can you maybe edit your question and add a little bit of info about the exact alteration and why the Views UI is not sufficient for that? Like why do you want to do this programmatically? Many thanks

Comment: same todo like @leymannx said above. In additional, if you know clear about hook_view_query_alter, you can place that function inside .module like this format : function module_name_view_query_alter(.......){....} . Good luck!